# Creating a legal bibliography and citation style from scratch

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

### General infos

I'm a law student in Switzerland and I discovered about a week the beauty of LaTeX after having a big fight with MSWord (over pretty much everything).

I got around the basics (paper and text formatting, inserting a citation, creating a bibliography, etc.) but now I am stuck with THE major problem why I abandoned MSWord to LaTeX: **bibliography and citation** ***styles***.

I am using **TeXShop** and **MacTeX** on Mac for the typesetting, as well as **JabRef** to organise my bibliography.

### Problem

In Switzerland, if you want to write a **legal document** (article, book, essay for university), you need to obey certain rules concerning bibliography and indexes, as well as the citation formats. They do ***not*** correspond to ***any*** of the classical styles available around the world (e.g. APA, MLA, IEEE).

I found an interesting package on CTAN (`biblatex-swiss-legal`, [accessible here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-swiss-legal?lang=en)) that would have allowed me to avoid ask this question here. Unfortunately, the package hasn't been updated since `biblatex`'s last update (at least 2014), especially concerning the `namelabel` parameters. I was successful in fixing most of the bugs, but a few are too tough for a newbie TeX user to handle.

I therefore decided to create my own bibliography and citation style, *ex nihilo*, from scratch.

### Questions

My questions are mainly concerning the **general** aspects of creating a bibliography and citation style, I'll find the specific commands afterwards on the different forums:

1. Is there any way to avoid using `biblatex`, `natbib` & co. while writing that .bst/.cst-file?
2. What is the utility of `biber` in this context?
3. Is `makebst` ran on Terminal really useful, or can I just encode the styles directly as a UTF-8 file?
4. What are the basic essentials I need to include in the document?

I know that wanting to create a personal bibliography and citation style without that much of an experience on TeX may seem crazy (and/or naive), but the original motive for which to change to LaTeX is precisely these characteristics of a scientific paper: uniform bibliographic and citing styles. I'm willing to spend a great deal of time to get this done when I'll start university in September. And as the French saying claims: «c'est en forgeant qu'on devient forgeron» (practise makes perfect)!

Comment: Just a few observations: biblatex is much easier to customise than .bst files (which are written in Reverse Polish Notation and use a syntax very different from TeX). Biber is more powerful than bibtex, and understands UTF8, which bibtex does not.

Comment: @Bernard That's the most appealing thing anyone's ever said about BST files. Is it really just WFF 'N PROOF in reverse?!!

Comment: Really, this question is much too broad. It is asking about ***way*** more than can possibly be covered in an answer here. Moreover, it will be much easier to fix up the existing style you found if it is just a question of updating it for current Biblatex. Saying that's beyond the ken of a new user and then saying you want to start some sort of bibliography style from scratch is ... really ... crazy. I appreciate your enthusiasm and that you are willing to spend time on this, but don't start off by attempting something which would dampen *anybody's* enthusiasm. Use your time more effectively!

Comment: (1) Biblatex case: does not apply. natbib case: yes. (2) Which context? It takes a list of citation keys and pulls out the entries for those keys from a database, preprocessing and sorting the data to create a file of the data associated with those keys in a form Biblatex can use. (3) Unanswerable. `makebst` is certainly useful. UTF-8 is inapplicable if `makebst` is in the picture because BibTeX doesn't do UTF-8 and `makebst` creates BST files for BibTeX. If you learn the language, you can write a `.bst` directly (not in UTF-8). (4) Which document? The style must cover every entry type needed.

Comment: @cfr: my bad, I got rather confused with all the names and the possible "marriages" between them. I started reading the `biblatex` explanation pdf, saw a lot of the things I might be interested in, so I guess I'll stick by it for the moment. I thought that writing a `.bst` would require the same "language" (syntax?) than TeX (beginners naiveness, mea culpa). Thanks a lot for your answers and your tips!

Comment: A small touch of humour with another quotation, from the French painter and poet Jean Arp: ‘C'est en écrivant qu'on devient écrevisse’ (untranslatable – une écrevisse is a crayfish).