# Adding "Cited as" next to each bibliography item in the bibliography of a thesis

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, back-referencing

I am working on a thesis (in french), and using biblatex to manage my citations with [geschichtsfrkl](https://ctan.org/pkg/geschichtsfrkl?lang=en) as the style for defining citations. In my thesis, I am using `\printbibliography` to display all my citations in the Bibliography chapter.

My university asks specifically about adding "***cited as (cité in french)***" next to each item in the bibliography (refer to the following examples):

> Asimov Issac, *The naked Sun*, London 2018. (cité : Asimov.)
>
> Algan Yann / Cazenave Thomas, *L'État en mode start-up*, 1e éd., Paris 2016. (cité : Algann / Cazenave.)

I searched a lot and understood that this is some sort of back referencing, and the "cited as" that I want is the *short citation* format that uses the last names (in Small Capitals) separated by a slash (/).

But, I don't know how to achieve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Following is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    french,
    10 pt,              
    openright
]{article}              
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=geschichtsfrkl,
backend=biber,
sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\thesis.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\thesis.bib}

@article{deroudille2019extraterritorialite,
  title={L’extraterritorialit{\'e} du RGPD dans le contexte du “Cloud Act”},
  author={Deroudille, Alexis and Fatah, Farid},
  journal={Revue du marche commun et de l'Union Europ{\'e}enne},
  number={630},
  pages={442--452},
  year={2019},
  publisher={{\'E}ditions Techniques et Economiques}
}

@article{decaux1987application,
  title={L'application extraterritoriale du droit {\'e}conomique},
  journal = {Cahiers du Centre de Droit International de Nanterre},
  number = {3},
  author={Decaux, Emmanuel},
  year={1987},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}

@article{lehmann_m_legal_2017,
    title = {Legal fragmentation, extraterritoriality and uncertainty in global financial regulation},
    volume = {37},
    issn = {0143-6503},
    %language = {English},
    number = {2},
    journal = {Oxford Journal of Legal Studies},
    author = {{Lehmann}, Matthias},
    pages = {406-434},
    year = {2017},
    note = {OCLC: 7086651768},
    pages = {406--434}
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Bibliographie}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it too late to switch from `style=geschichtsfrkl,` to a more standard style like `style=verbose,`? `geschichtsfrkl` does some things in very non-standard ways and seems to be tricky to modify.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes! The thesis is almost finished.

Comment: In the worst case, I was thinking of adding a "note" field to each bibitem, and printing this note when printing the bibliography. Also, defining it in the style how to print the note field.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm a bit busy at the moment and probably won't manage to look into this today. You can have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427231/35864 for an implementation of `citedas`. In theory it should be possible to adapt this to your situation, but I haven't had a look at how difficult that is.

Comment: Thanks @moewe, that's very kind of you. I quickly tried and it gave an error. I will spend some time on your suggested solution later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following adds a "cited as"/"cité" info to the bibliography that relies on `cite:short`. So the output there should be the same output you get in the citations if you cite the entry multiple times.

I took the code for the `citedas` macro from my answer to [Formatting issue with DeclareBibliographyDriver in my Custom Biblatex Style based](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427231/35864).

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=geschichtsfrkl,
  sorting=nyt,
  citecounter,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
  citedas = {cit\'e},
}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \ifbibliography
    {\setunit{\finentrypunct\space}%
     \ifnumgreater{\value{citecounter}}{0}
       {\usebibmacro{citedas}%
        \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}}
       {}}
    {}%
  \finentry}

\newbibmacro{citedas}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \bibstring{citedas}%
    \addcolon\space
    \usebibmacro{citedas:cite}}}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro{citedas:cite}{%
  \begingroup
    \delimcontext{cite}%
    \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
    \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
    \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
    \undef\cbx@lasthash
    \undef\cbx@lastyear
    \citetrackerfalse\pagetrackerfalse\backtrackerfalse
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:short}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother



\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{deroudille,
  title   = {L'extraterritorialité du RGPD dans le contexte du “Cloud Act”},
  author  = {Deroudille, Alexis and Fatah, Farid},
  journal = {Revue du marche commun et de l'Union Européenne},
  number  = {630},
  pages   = {442--452},
  year    = {2019},
}
@article{decaux,
  title   = {L'application extraterritoriale du droit économique},
  journal = {Cahiers du Centre de Droit International de Nanterre},
  number  = {3},
  author  = {Decaux, Emmanuel},
  year    = {1987},
}
@article{lehmann,
  title   = {Legal fragmentation, extraterritoriality and uncertainty
             in global financial regulation},
  volume  = {37},
  issn    = {0143-6503},
  number  = {2},
  journal = {Oxford Journal of Legal Studies},
  author  = {Lehmann, Matthias},
  pages   = {406-434},
  year    = {2017},
  note    = {OCLC: 7086651768},
  pages   = {406--434},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
Lorem\footcite{lehmann} ipsum\footcite{decaux}
Lorem\footcite{lehmann} ipsum

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Decaux, Emmanuel : L’application extraterritoriale du droit économique, in : Cahiers du Centre de Droit International de Nanterre 3 (1987). (Cité : Decaux, E. : L’application extraterritoriale du droit économique [1987])]

Comment: Dear moewe, that is amazing. It absolutely works well. Many thanks :)
One more request, is there a way to add this "cité" only for the entries which were cited in the thesis? I am using \printbibliography to print all the references. Thanks for any input or direction about what to look for?

Comment: @HimanshuVerma Sure, that is possible. See the edit, please. With `\ifnumgreater{\value{citecounter}}{0}` only entries that were cited get the *cité* information. With `\ifnumgreater{\value{citecounter}}{1}` you would only add it to entries which were cited in the short form.

Comment: it works perfectly for the entry type `books`, Many many thanks for your great help! 
However, for `article`, `inproceedings`, `phdthesis`, and other types it does not work. Any idea, why it could be happening?

Comment: @HimanshuVerma All entries in the example are `@article`s and it appears to work for me (appears to work as in: I get output that seems sensible). What do you see and what would you like to see instead?

Comment: With the previous solution, I could see (Cité: ...) with all entry types. Now, I only see them for the books, and not for other types. Meaning I do not see the (Cité: ...) for other types.

Comment: Also, I am using different `\printbibliography` statements. First, I am using it to print the books, and then I am using it again (with a different section header) to print other kinds of entries. Maybe, it could be the potential culprit?

Comment: @HimanshuVerma Sorry, I can not reproduce that behaviour. If I run the MWE exactly as posted I get the *cité* output for `decaux` and `lehmann`, which are `@article` entries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103216/discussion-between-moewe-and-himanshu-verma).