# How to fix a bug due to bibtex 3.3 naming changes?

Tags: biblatex

I want to use a special and uncommon option package for bibtex: BIBLATEX-SWISS-LEGAL-BASE [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-swiss-legal). I resume my document as following:

```
\documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[style=biblatex-swiss-legal-bibliography, backend=biber]{biblatex}   %The code work with default config
\begin{filecontents}{Sandbox.bib}
    @misc{LoursKnuth,
        author = {Lours, Donald},
        year = {1977},
        title = {L'origine du monde},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{Sandbox.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
Je doute de mes capacités à résoudre ce problème \cite{LoursKnuth}.
\end{document}
```

Since the transformation of bibtex 3.3 the package is no more usable and display this kind of error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d.
<to be read again>
5
l.355 \usebibmacro{name:last}{\ifblank{#5}{}{\textsc{#5}\addspace}\textsc...
You meant to type ## instead of #, right? Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

I imagine that the package has to be maintained but meanwhile is it possible to use a simple "fix tip" for all this. As far as I didn't write myself the package, make correction in the macros is not possible for me (like in [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299036/biblatex-3-3-name-formatting/299084#299084)).

I remplaced the biblatex-swiss-legal-base provided by @moewe as suggested in [answer about the same problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426142/bibliography-using-biblatex-swiss-legal-not-displayed-correctly/426174#426174). it didn't fix completly the problem, the following error appear:

```
l.215 \DeclareSortingTemplate
{ntyintro}{% Code en test non mentionné dans l...
The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

it happens in the corrected .bbs [avaiable here](https://gist.github.com/moewew/c15dcbe6a7a23e007a9ed65b7d7aa567).
and then a worst one:
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Comment: There is an unofficial update for `biblatex-swiss-legal-bibliography` written by moewe, the developer of BibLaTeX. You can download it from https://gist.github.com/moewew/c15dcbe6a7a23e007a9ed65b7d7aa567, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426142/bibliography-using-biblatex-swiss-legal-not-displayed-correctly. I checked and it works with your MWE. To use it you should download the file, put it in the same directory as your `.tex` file and remove the `-new` part from the filename.

Comment: Thank you! I completed my question, because it doesn't work yet...

Comment: Which version of `biblatex` do you use? You can find the version number in the log file (search for `Package: biblatex`). The `\DeclareSortingTemplate` macro was introduced in version 3.8, November 2017.

Comment: Indeed, i've got an older version of  biblatex. I reinstall a new LTS and brand new texlive.
It works queit well whith this patch! That's truely great. Wouldn't be possible to write it in the CTAN biblatex-swiss-legal page that this unofficial update exists? I wrote to both last maintainer, but waiting for their answer it would be great to make this update circulating...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm the author of the changed version of the `.bbx` file Marijn linked in their comment above. I have no intention of uploading the changed version to CTAN nor do I intend to support or maintain the ad-hoc changes I made for future versions of `biblatex` of my own accord. I will, however, consider my changes to the original file to be made under the LPPL so that it would be possible for anyone who is interested to use and/or distribute the file in the same way as the `biblatex-swiss-legal` package. ...

Comment: ... If the author of the package does not respond to e-mails or can not maintain the package any longer, I would consider the project dead and would recommend against using the package in any new projects (and would even urge people to consider migrating to a different style for projects that are already running).